# What happens if the auction nominator is outbid?

Tags: power-grid

Seeking clarification on this issue:

In Powergrid, at the Auction phase, a player has the choice of passing, or nominating a powerplant for auction.

If they nominate the powerplant for auction, they must put the first bid on it.

If someone subsequently outbids them, what happens? 
My understanding, is that the player then nominates a second powerplant (or still has the option of passing?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is exactly correct. From the [rules](http://file:///C:/Users/Robert/Downloads/Game_5_gameRules.pdf):

> When the auctioning player wins the auction and gets the power plant, the next player in turn order takes his turn at offering a power plant for auction, if he has not
>    already purchased a power plant this round. If he has, the next player in turn order may start an auction, and so on. **When a player other than the player who started
>    the auction wins the auction, the auctioning player may choose a new plant to auction from the actual market or pass.**